# Problema exportando Excel con un loop de peticiones HTTP

Tags: javascript, angular, asincronismo, xls

Estoy usando la librería xlsxjs para exportar un archivo Excel.
La información que exporto, la obtengo consumiendo un servicio por cada registro en un Array.
Ejecuta todo bien pero al exportar el Excel y abrirlo, no hay información.

Probé poniéndole un setTimeOut() a la función que exporta el Excel y si funcionó.

¿Cómo puedo solucionar ese problema sin recurrir al setTiemOut()?

Así no funciona

```js
items.map((value, index) => {
      value.tipoobjeto == 17 && value.idpantalla ? this.pantallasService.getpantallas(0, { id: value.idpantalla }).subscribe(res => {
        ws[`B${countY}`] = {t: 's', v: 'Nombre Pantalla'}
        ws[`C${countY}`] = {t: 's', v: res.items[0].nombrepantalla}
        countY += 1
        ws[`B${countY}`] = {t: 's', v: 'Nemotécnico Pantalla'}
        ws[`C${countY}`] = {t: 's', v: res.items[0].nemotecnicopantalla}
        countY += 1
        ws[`B${countY}`] = {t: 's', v: 'Ubicación Menú'}
        ws[`C${countY}`] = {t: 's', v: res.items[0].ubicacionmenu}
        countY += 1
      }) : null
    })

    XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws, 'Especificaciones')
    const excelBuffer: any = XLSX.write(wb, {
      bookType: "xlsx",
      type: "array",
    });

    this.excelService.saveAsExcelFile(excelBuffer, "Necesidades");
```

Así si funciona

```js
    items.map((value, index) => {
      value.tipoobjeto == 17 && value.idpantalla ? this.pantallasService.getpantallas(0, { id: value.idpantalla }).subscribe(res => {
        ws[`B${countY}`] = { t: 's', v: 'Nombre Pantalla' }
        ws[`C${countY}`] = { t: 's', v: res.items[0].nombrepantalla }
        countY += 1
        ws[`B${countY}`] = { t: 's', v: 'Nemotécnico Pantalla' }
        ws[`C${countY}`] = { t: 's', v: res.items[0].nemotecnicopantalla }
        countY += 1
        ws[`B${countY}`] = { t: 's', v: 'Ubicación Menú' }
        ws[`C${countY}`] = { t: 's', v: res.items[0].ubicacionmenu }
        countY += 1
      }) : null
    })

    setTimeout(() => {
      XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws, 'Especificaciones')
      const excelBuffer: any = XLSX.write(wb, {
        bookType: "xlsx",
        type: "array",
      });

      this.excelService.saveAsExcelFile(excelBuffer, "Necesidades");
    }, 2000)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu problema viene por que te suscribes a un observable que no sabes cuando se resuelve, por lo que si lo asignas directamente no tiene los valores resueltos.

Y con el timeout espera esos segundos y ya se completaron tus peticiones por eso se ven los valores, pero aun así tienes aun probabilidades que no este generado tu resultado si tarda en regresar tu respuesta.

Lo que deberías de hacer es usar un [forkJoin](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/forkJoin) de la librería rxjs.

```
// Filtra los ítems que se van a mandar al forkJoin, al final con el map regresara los observables para subscribirse
let subscribers =  forkJoin(
    items.filter((e) => e.tipoobjeto === 17 && e.idpantalla ).map(
        (value, index) => {
            return this.pantallasService.getpantallas(0, { id: value.idpantalla })
        }
    )
);

//Aquí se subscribe al forkjoin, y se resolverá cuando todos los observables se hayan completado.
subscribers.subscribe((results: Array<any>) => {
    // como no hay un numero fijo de elementos, todos los recibe en results,
    // Y recorre todos los objetos que recorrio.
    results.forEach((value, index) => {
        ws[`B${countY}`] = { t: 's', v: 'Nombre Pantalla' }
        ws[`C${countY}`] = { t: 's', v: value.items[0].nombrepantalla }
        countY += 1
        ws[`B${countY}`] = { t: 's', v: 'Nemotécnico Pantalla' }
        ws[`C${countY}`] = { t: 's', v: value.items[0].nemotecnicopantalla }
        countY += 1
        ws[`B${countY}`] = { t: 's', v: 'Ubicación Menú' }
        ws[`C${countY}`] = { t: 's', v: value.items[0].ubicacionmenu }
        countY += 1
    });
    
    //Aquí ya debe contener todos los valores en ws.
    XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws, 'Especificaciones')
        const excelBuffer: any = XLSX.write(wb, {
            bookType: "xlsx",
            type: "array",
    });

    this.excelService.saveAsExcelFile(excelBuffer, "Necesidades");
})
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!! 
Funcionó a la perfección.

Comment: Pregunta, necesito consumir dos servicios por cada item. Uno es el de this.pantallasService.getpantallas(0, { id: value.idpantalla }) y otro es this.getInfoCamposPantalla(0, {idbloque: value.idbloque}). No logro hacerlo.

Comment: tienes que meter tus otros servicios en el forkjoin, y validar el tipo de respuesta, no te recomiendo llenar directo el ws, creo seria mejor que generes un array de tus objetos y una vez que lo tengas listo recórrelo y añádelo al ws,

Comment: puedes usar el mismo forkJoin y manejar todas las peticiones ahí, o generar otro y subscribirte cuando se completen las primeras, para así asegurar tu flujo que tengas todo.

Comment: let infoPantallas = forkJoin(
      items.filter((e) => e.tipoobjeto == 17 && e.idpantalla).map(
        (value, index) => {
          return[this.pantallasService.getpantallas(0, {id: value.idpantalla}),
            this.getInfoCamposPantalla(0, {idbloque: value.idbloque})]
        }
      )
    )
¿Así?